# Static member variables holds the value '0' at which state?

Tags: c++

`static` member variable holds the value `0` at which state?

When we declare it?

```
static int x;
```

OR when we define it?

```
int Simple::x;
```

Comment: Assigning it to 0 is not necessary. I have tested it and it outputs 0 but I wanted to know if it contains 0 before hand. But as you said, it contains random. Thanks. :)

Comment: you need to affect it. `int simple::x = 0;`

Comment: It should not contained 0 before hand. I'm surprised I actually compiles without affectation.

Comment: @user2346536 Static member variables are zero initialised. They do not contain the previous garbage memory.

Comment: Well I learned something today... in @Armen Tsirunyan below answer. thanks to both of you...

Comment: @Drax thanks, I did not know that. I always assigned my static members. I did not know of the specific case of POD types.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization

Comment: @user2346536 it's the static storage qualifier who has this consequence, nothing to do with POD types ^^

Comment: @Drax So I can declare without assignment, some static member class? And the whole memory would be assigned to 00000 ?

Comment: @user2346536 Yes, your static data is placed in a section called bss (at least in the ELF format, i don't know the PE equivalent) which is zero initialised for historical reasons mostly ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither would make sense, since the declaration and definition have nothing to do with the runtime state of the program.

It's initialised to zero during the static initialisation stage as the program starts, before any user code is run.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler initializes it to 0 on declaration unless you assign it any other value.

Comment: what does visual studio 2013 has to do with this? Point us to standard not specification of microsoft compiler.

Comment: The starting paragraph sums up static keyword in a real brief way. That's what it's got to be with it though I agree with your objection, hence i'd be taking the URL off the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The object is created by a definition, not declaration. So it would be less erroneous to say that it is the definition that initializes your object. However, you don't know the exact time when this will happen. You just know that this will happen before main is called. That's why I sayd less erroneous rather than more correct.

And yes, static data members of built-in type are zero-initialized by default.

Answer (score 1):

All static data is initialized to zero when the first object is created, if no other initialization is present.